# How to access second disk locally and over LAN

Tags: networking, hard-drive, share, lan

I have just added a second 1TB HD to my Ubuntu box and I can see it listed when I run `blkid`. But how do I

1. reference it so I can use it as local storage
2. share it on my LAN

Comment: have you created a filesystem and partitions on it?

Comment: No I don't think so. I formatted it as mac journalled and it is visible in Ubuntu but I dont know do I have to mount it or something? Perhaps reformat it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what you want to do:

First, open up disk utility and select your hard drive in the sidebar:

[image]

Now, click the little "Create Partition" icon. Make sure you're selecting the right drive, this is the dangerous part!

[image]

Now, lets get this drive mounted on our computer.

[image]

Click that, and then it will mount on your computer. Navigate to it and then right click on it, then select Properties. Navigate to the "Sharing" tab:

[image]

Then, check the "Share This Folder" box.

[image]

Select  "Install Service".

[image]

Select "Install".

[image]

Then you will see that - enter in your password and follow the rest of the prompts.

When its done, it will ask you to install another piece of software, and then when that is done it will ask to restart your session - to do that, save any of your other work, and then click "Yes".

Come back in, and then find the directory (folder) that you want to share, and then share it like we did above (it might already be shared, I had two different computers and I had to check it on one computer, and on the other it was already done. *shrug*)

Anyway, to connect to it on your other computer, click the "Browse Network" item in the Nautilus sidebar:

[image]

And then find the share that we want to connect to, and then just go from there! Enjoy the shared networking goodness! :)

Answer (score 4):

1. launch gparted. (if its not installed "sudo apt-get install gparted")
2. select the disk from the drop-down menu to the right.
3. right click on the disk and select new if available, else select format to and select ext4 or someother linux format
4. press the green checkmark at the top to commit your changes

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Or you could keep it as HFS, but i would guess that if you going to have it in your ubuntu box it might be wiser to have it formatted to a Linux format. [link](https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write)

After you have created the partition you will have to make sure that it get mounted every time, first create a mountpoint

1. eg. sudo mkdir /media/newname and setup wanted permissions eg. sudo chmod 777 /media/newname
2. open up fstab and add a line to it: "sudo gedit /etc/fstab" and add something like 
   /dev/sdbX    /media/newname    ext4    defaults    0    2 (you can see the sdbX part in gparted)
3. remount with "sudo mount -a" and make sure it worked

[fstab help](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html)

After that is done and if samba is installed you should be able to just right click the new folder and select share.
[a link on how to setup samba](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202605)

Comment: So once I have reformatted it who do I share it over my network? I hear talk of Samba??

Comment: If I format the disk as ext4 will is be writable when I mount it in OS X?

Comment: if you mean as a network resource sure. if you mean physically mount the disk in a osx it is possible http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mac-os-x-read-ext3-ext4-external-usb-hard-disk-partition/

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!